# How to handle back navigation with Jetpack Compose + Navigation (without fragments)

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am trying to navigate lets say from onboarding to dashboard and beyond and pop the onboarding once user hits dashboard, but still with 'back action' I end up on onboarding again.

Here is the sample code:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MainUI()
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun MainUI() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "onboarding"
    ) {
        composable("onboarding") {
            Column {
                Text("I am on onboarding")
                Button(onClick = {
                    navController.navigate("dashboard") {
                        popUpTo("dashboard") // I want to get rid of onboarding here
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("go to dashboard")
                }
            }
        }
        composable("dashboard") {
            Column {
                Text("I am on dashboard")
                Button(onClick = {
                    navController.navigate("detail")
                }) {
                    Text("go to detail")
                }
            }
        }
        composable("detail") {
            Text("I am on detail")
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work either

```
navController.navigate("dashboard") {
    popUpTo("dashboard") {
            inclusive = true // no difference
        }

// ....

    popUpTo("onboarding") // also nothing

// ....

    popUpTo("onboarding") {
            inclusive = true // this crashes -> NavGraph cannot be cast to ComposeNavigator$Destination
        }

}
```

For some reason this kind of works, so dashboard is dismissed and from detail I end up on onboarding

```
navController.navigate("detail") {
     popUpTo("dashboard") {
            inclusive = true
     }
}
```

Answer (score 35):

I found my solution very easy, if I'm wrong please enlighten me.

```
navController.popBackStack()
```

Comment: How did you instantiate `navController`?

Answer (score 16):

You can use BackHandler [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary#backhandler):

```
@Composable
    fun TestScreen() {
        BackHandler {
             // code
            // example - activity.finish()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think it works, BackHandler is not intercepted until the last navigation in which it exits the app. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As @James Christian Kaguo already said `navController.popBackStack()` is an option. But you have to be careful when using this method. For some Reason the size of the BackQueue is at least 2 and if popping the backstack lower than that, navigation does not seem to work anymore.

Therefore I wrote following simple extension function:

```
fun NavController.navigateBack() {
    if (backQueue.size > 2) {
        popBackStack()
    }
}
```

Comment: As of navigation-compose:2.6.0, backqueue is private.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've found working solution myself, still not sure if this "boilerplate code" is needed :(
But this works as intended, means "page" is dismissed once navigated from it.

```
NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "onboarding"
    ) {
        navigation(
            startDestination = "onboardingUI",
            route = "onboarding"
        ) {
            composable("onboardingUI") {
                Column {
                    Text("I am on onboarding")
                    Button(onClick = {
                        navController.navigate("dashboard"){
                            popUpTo("onboarding")
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("go to dashboard")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        navigation(startDestination = "dashboardUI", route = "dashboard") {
            composable("dashboardUI") {
                Column {
                    Text("I am on dashboard")
                    Button(onClick = {
                        navController.navigate("detail"){
                            popUpTo("dashboard")
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("go to detail")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        navigation(startDestination = "detailUI", route = "detail") {
            composable("detailUI") {
                Text("I am on detail")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: *route* and *startDestination* AKA name of the composable cannot be same

Comment: You just need to ThinkDeep ;)